# Flip most of an svg image, but not the text within it

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, svg

I have a big collection of svg images like this:
[image]

```
<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g stroke="lightgray" stroke-dasharray="1,1" stroke-width="1" transform="scale(4, 4)">
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="256" y2="256"></line>
    <line x1="256" y1="0" x2="0" y2="256"></line>
    <line x1="128" y1="0" x2="128" y2="256"></line>
    <line x1="0" y1="128" x2="256" y2="128"></line>
  </g>
  <g transform="scale(1, -1) translate(0, -900)">
      <style>
        .stroke1 {fill: #BF0909;}
        .stroke2 {fill: #BFBF09;}
        .stroke3 {fill: #09BF09;}
        .stroke4 {fill: #09BFBF;}
        .stroke5 {fill: #0909BF;}
        .stroke6 {fill: #BF09BF;}
        .stroke7 {fill: #BFBFBF;}
        .stroke8 {fill: #090909;}
      </style>

      <path class="stroke1" d="M 272 567 Q 306 613 342 669 Q 370 718 395 743 Q 405 753 400 769 Q 396 782 365 808 Q 337 827 316 828 Q 297 827 305 802 Q 318 769 306 741 Q 267 647 207 560 Q 150 476 72 385 Q 60 375 58 367 Q 54 355 70 358 Q 82 359 109 384 Q 155 421 213 493 Q 226 509 241 527 L 272 567 Z" fill="#BF0909"></path>

      <path class="stroke2" d="M 241 527 Q 262 506 258 375 Q 258 374 258 370 Q 254 253 221 135 Q 215 114 224 80 Q 236 44 248 32 Q 267 16 279 44 Q 294 86 294 134 Q 303 420 314 485 Q 321 515 295 543 Q 289 549 272 567 C 251 589 227 553 241 527 Z" fill="lightgray"></path>

      <path class="stroke3" d="M 521 560 Q 561 621 602 708 Q 620 751 638 773 Q 645 786 639 799 Q 633 811 602 830 Q 572 846 554 843 Q 535 839 546 817 Q 561 795 552 757 Q 513 619 407 448 Q 398 436 397 430 Q 394 418 409 423 Q 439 432 503 532 L 521 560 Z" fill="lightgray"></path>

      <path class="stroke4" d="M 503 532 Q 527 510 555 520 Q 795 608 782 549 Q 783 543 743 468 Q 736 458 741 453 Q 745 447 756 459 Q 852 532 894 549 Q 904 552 905 561 Q 906 574 876 592 Q 852 605 828 621 Q 800 637 783 630 Q 686 590 521 560 C 492 555 479 550 503 532 Z" fill="lightgray"></path>

      <path class="stroke5" d="M 568 72 Q 531 81 494 91 Q 482 94 483 86 Q 484 79 494 71 Q 569 7 596 -33 Q 611 -49 626 -36 Q 659 -3 661 82 Q 655 149 655 345 Q 656 382 667 407 Q 676 426 659 439 Q 634 461 604 470 Q 585 477 577 469 Q 571 462 582 447 Q 619 384 603 127 Q 597 82 589 74 Q 582 67 568 72 Z" fill="lightgray"></path>

      <path class="stroke6" d="M 444 320 Q 419 262 385 208 Q 364 180 381 144 Q 388 128 409 139 Q 460 181 468 264 Q 472 295 467 319 Q 463 328 456 328 Q 449 327 444 320 Z" fill="lightgray"></path>

      <path class="stroke7" d="M 738 307 Q 789 249 847 168 Q 860 146 876 139 Q 885 138 893 146 Q 908 159 900 204 Q 891 264 743 338 Q 734 345 731 332 Q 728 319 738 307 Z" fill="lightgray"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

and list of coordinates for each image on which a number has to be drawn (see text-elements of following svg code). The problem is: When I add the required text elements, they are flipped vertically and horizontally:
[image]

```
<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g stroke="lightgray" stroke-dasharray="1,1" stroke-width="1" transform="scale(4, 4)">
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="256" y2="256"></line>
    <line x1="256" y1="0" x2="0" y2="256"></line>
    <line x1="128" y1="0" x2="128" y2="256"></line>
    <line x1="0" y1="128" x2="256" y2="128"></line>
  </g>
  <g transform="scale(1, -1) translate(0, -900)">
      <style>
        .stroke1 {fill: #BF0909;}
        .stroke2 {fill: #BFBF09;}
        .stroke3 {fill: #09BF09;}
        .stroke4 {fill: #09BFBF;}
        .stroke5 {fill: #0909BF;}
        .stroke6 {fill: #BF09BF;}
        .stroke7 {fill: #BFBFBF;}
        .stroke8 {fill: #090909;}
        text {
            font-family: Helvetica;
            font-size: 80px;
            fill: #FFFFFF;
            paint-order: stroke;
            stroke: #000000;
            stroke-width: 4px;
            stroke-linecap: butt;
            stroke-linejoin: miter;
            font-weight: 800;
        }
      </style>
      <path class="stroke1" d="M 272 567 Q 306 613 342 669 Q 370 718 395 743 Q 405 753 400 769 Q 396 782 365 808 Q 337 827 316 828 Q 297 827 305 802 Q 318 769 306 741 Q 267 647 207 560 Q 150 476 72 385 Q 60 375 58 367 Q 54 355 70 358 Q 82 359 109 384 Q 155 421 213 493 Q 226 509 241 527 L 272 567 Z" fill="#BF0909"></path>

      <path class="stroke2" d="M 241 527 Q 262 506 258 375 Q 258 374 258 370 Q 254 253 221 135 Q 215 114 224 80 Q 236 44 248 32 Q 267 16 279 44 Q 294 86 294 134 Q 303 420 314 485 Q 321 515 295 543 Q 289 549 272 567 C 251 589 227 553 241 527 Z" fill="lightgray"></path>

      <path class="stroke3" d="M 521 560 Q 561 621 602 708 Q 620 751 638 773 Q 645 786 639 799 Q 633 811 602 830 Q 572 846 554 843 Q 535 839 546 817 Q 561 795 552 757 Q 513 619 407 448 Q 398 436 397 430 Q 394 418 409 423 Q 439 432 503 532 L 521 560 Z" fill="lightgray"></path>

      <path class="stroke4" d="M 503 532 Q 527 510 555 520 Q 795 608 782 549 Q 783 543 743 468 Q 736 458 741 453 Q 745 447 756 459 Q 852 532 894 549 Q 904 552 905 561 Q 906 574 876 592 Q 852 605 828 621 Q 800 637 783 630 Q 686 590 521 560 C 492 555 479 550 503 532 Z" fill="lightgray"></path>

      <path class="stroke5" d="M 568 72 Q 531 81 494 91 Q 482 94 483 86 Q 484 79 494 71 Q 569 7 596 -33 Q 611 -49 626 -36 Q 659 -3 661 82 Q 655 149 655 345 Q 656 382 667 407 Q 676 426 659 439 Q 634 461 604 470 Q 585 477 577 469 Q 571 462 582 447 Q 619 384 603 127 Q 597 82 589 74 Q 582 67 568 72 Z" fill="lightgray"></path>

      <path class="stroke6" d="M 444 320 Q 419 262 385 208 Q 364 180 381 144 Q 388 128 409 139 Q 460 181 468 264 Q 472 295 467 319 Q 463 328 456 328 Q 449 327 444 320 Z" fill="lightgray"></path>

      <path class="stroke7" d="M 738 307 Q 789 249 847 168 Q 860 146 876 139 Q 885 138 893 146 Q 908 159 900 204 Q 891 264 743 338 Q 734 345 731 332 Q 728 319 738 307 Z" fill="lightgray"></path>

      <text x="317" y="812">1</text>
      <text x="273" y="558">2</text>
      <text x="556" y="828">3</text>
      <text x="513" y="532">4</text>
      <text x="586" y="463">5</text>
      <text x="455" y="316">6</text>
      <text x="742" y="326">7</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I just can't figure out a way to get the text to be displayed at the right position without without it being flipped horizontally and vertically. I already tried to wrap the text in another g-tag and do the transform again do revert it, but then the text would disappear. I also tried to move the text out of the original g-tag, but then my coordinates aren't valid anymore...

**Edit:** I'm looking for a way to generate the svgs in a way that they are compatible with Safari (on Windows), Chrome and Firefox.

**Edit2:** Unfortunately I can't use `transform-box` because I need to support a Safari based browser which doesn't support it.

Comment: You say you want to "generate" the SVGs. Does that mean processing the SVG files to alter them is a viable option? On-the-fly or once-and-for-all?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. I'm using NodeJs with Cheerio to manipulate the SVG and then I save it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Manipulating the SVG, all you need to do is

- move the `<text>` elements outside the group with the `transform` attribute
- recompute the `y` attribute with

  ```
  y -> 940 - y
  ```

  This supposes that the transform attribute is always `transform="scale(1, -1) translate(0, -900)"` and the font size `80px`. A general formula would be

  ```
  y -> (negative y translation + font size / 2) - y
  ```

Here is a node script utilizing cheerio to change existing files:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const $ = cheerio.load(xmlText, { xmlMode: true });

function flipTextInPlace ($) {
    $('text').each(() => {
       const y = $(this).attr('y');
       $(this).attr('y', 940 - y);
    }).appendTo('svg');
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the Safari-based browser that I need to support doesn't support the "transform-box" property.

Comment: I've exchanged my answer for a different one. Please reconsider your votes.

Comment: Thank you. Worked like a charm after using fontSize/2. I upvoted your answer in the first place, I don't see a reason to change that. ;)

Answer (score 9):

I hope this helps:

```css
text:nth-child(1) {
  transform: scale(1, -1);
  transform-origin: 317px 812px;/*same as text coords*/
  dominant-baseline: hanging;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g stroke="lightgray" stroke-dasharray="1,1" stroke-width="1" transform="scale(4, 4)">
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="256" y2="256"></line>
    <line x1="256" y1="0" x2="0" y2="256"></line>
    <line x1="128" y1="0" x2="128" y2="256"></line>
    <line x1="0" y1="128" x2="256" y2="128"></line>
  </g>
  <g transform="scale(1, -1) translate(0, -900)">
      <style>
        .stroke1 {fill: #BF0909;}
        .stroke2 {fill: #BFBF09;}
        .stroke3 {fill: #09BF09;}
        .stroke4 {fill: #09BFBF;}
        .stroke5 {fill: #0909BF;}
        .stroke6 {fill: #BF09BF;}
        .stroke7 {fill: #BFBFBF;}
        .stroke8 {fill: #090909;}
        text {
            font-family: Helvetica;
            font-size: 80px;
            fill: #FFFFFF;
            paint-order: stroke;
            stroke: #000000;
            stroke-width: 4px;
            stroke-linecap: butt;
            stroke-linejoin: miter;
            font-weight: 800;
        }
      </style>
      <path class="stroke1" d="M 272 567 Q 306 613 342 669 Q 370 718 395 743 Q 405 753 400 769 Q 396 782 365 808 Q 337 827 316 828 Q 297 827 305 802 Q 318 769 306 741 Q 267 647 207 560 Q 150 476 72 385 Q 60 375 58 367 Q 54 355 70 358 Q 82 359 109 384 Q 155 421 213 493 Q 226 509 241 527 L 272 567 Z" fill="#BF0909"></path>

      <path class="stroke2" d="M 241 527 Q 262 506 258 375 Q 258 374 258 370 Q 254 253 221 135 Q 215 114 224 80 Q 236 44 248 32 Q 267 16 279 44 Q 294 86 294 134 Q 303 420 314 485 Q 321 515 295 543 Q 289 549 272 567 C 251 589 227 553 241 527 Z" fill="lightgray"></path>

      <path class="stroke3" d="M 521 560 Q 561 621 602 708 Q 620 751 638 773 Q 645 786 639 799 Q 633 811 602 830 Q 572 846 554 843 Q 535 839 546 817 Q 561 795 552 757 Q 513 619 407 448 Q 398 436 397 430 Q 394 418 409 423 Q 439 432 503 532 L 521 560 Z" fill="lightgray"></path>

      <path class="stroke4" d="M 503 532 Q 527 510 555 520 Q 795 608 782 549 Q 783 543 743 468 Q 736 458 741 453 Q 745 447 756 459 Q 852 532 894 549 Q 904 552 905 561 Q 906 574 876 592 Q 852 605 828 621 Q 800 637 783 630 Q 686 590 521 560 C 492 555 479 550 503 532 Z" fill="lightgray"></path>

      <path class="stroke5" d="M 568 72 Q 531 81 494 91 Q 482 94 483 86 Q 484 79 494 71 Q 569 7 596 -33 Q 611 -49 626 -36 Q 659 -3 661 82 Q 655 149 655 345 Q 656 382 667 407 Q 676 426 659 439 Q 634 461 604 470 Q 585 477 577 469 Q 571 462 582 447 Q 619 384 603 127 Q 597 82 589 74 Q 582 67 568 72 Z" fill="lightgray"></path>

      <path class="stroke6" d="M 444 320 Q 419 262 385 208 Q 364 180 381 144 Q 388 128 409 139 Q 460 181 468 264 Q 472 295 467 319 Q 463 328 456 328 Q 449 327 444 320 Z" fill="lightgray"></path>

      <path class="stroke7" d="M 738 307 Q 789 249 847 168 Q 860 146 876 139 Q 885 138 893 146 Q 908 159 900 204 Q 891 264 743 338 Q 734 345 731 332 Q 728 319 738 307 Z" fill="lightgray"></path>
    
    <g>
      <text x="317" y="812">1</text>
      <text x="273" y="558">2</text>
      <text x="556" y="828">3</text>
      <text x="513" y="532">4</text>
      <text x="586" y="463">5</text>
      <text x="455" y="316">6</text>
      <text x="742" y="326">7</text>
    </g>
  </g>
 
</svg>
```

**Unfortunately** this works on Chrome & Firefox but not on Safari. Didn't check Edge & IE.

Answer (score 5):

You could use css transform on your text nodes

**Edit**

Inspired from @enxaneta answer, you could run this little script

```js
const text = document.querySelectorAll("text");

text.forEach(function(el){   
  el.style.transformOrigin = el.getAttribute('x')+'px '+el.getAttribute('y')+'px';
  el.style.transform = "scale(1,-1)";     
});
```

```css
text{
  dominant-baseline:central;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g stroke="lightgray" stroke-dasharray="1,1" stroke-width="1" transform="scale(4, 4)">
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="256" y2="256"></line>
    <line x1="256" y1="0" x2="0" y2="256"></line>
    <line x1="128" y1="0" x2="128" y2="256"></line>
    <line x1="0" y1="128" x2="256" y2="128"></line>
  </g>
  <g transform="scale(1, -1) translate(0, -900)">
      <style>
        .stroke1 {fill: #BF0909;}
        .stroke2 {fill: #BFBF09;}
        .stroke3 {fill: #09BF09;}
        .stroke4 {fill: #09BFBF;}
        .stroke5 {fill: #0909BF;}
        .stroke6 {fill: #BF09BF;}
        .stroke7 {fill: #BFBFBF;}
        .stroke8 {fill: #090909;}
        text {
            font-family: Helvetica;
            font-size: 80px;
            fill: #FFFFFF;
            paint-order: stroke;
            stroke: #000000;
            stroke-width: 4px;
            stroke-linecap: butt;
            stroke-linejoin: miter;
            font-weight: 800;
        }
      </style>
      <path class="stroke1" d="M 272 567 Q 306 613 342 669 Q 370 718 395 743 Q 405 753 400 769 Q 396 782 365 808 Q 337 827 316 828 Q 297 827 305 802 Q 318 769 306 741 Q 267 647 207 560 Q 150 476 72 385 Q 60 375 58 367 Q 54 355 70 358 Q 82 359 109 384 Q 155 421 213 493 Q 226 509 241 527 L 272 567 Z" fill="#BF0909"></path>

      <path class="stroke2" d="M 241 527 Q 262 506 258 375 Q 258 374 258 370 Q 254 253 221 135 Q 215 114 224 80 Q 236 44 248 32 Q 267 16 279 44 Q 294 86 294 134 Q 303 420 314 485 Q 321 515 295 543 Q 289 549 272 567 C 251 589 227 553 241 527 Z" fill="lightgray"></path>

      <path class="stroke3" d="M 521 560 Q 561 621 602 708 Q 620 751 638 773 Q 645 786 639 799 Q 633 811 602 830 Q 572 846 554 843 Q 535 839 546 817 Q 561 795 552 757 Q 513 619 407 448 Q 398 436 397 430 Q 394 418 409 423 Q 439 432 503 532 L 521 560 Z" fill="lightgray"></path>

      <path class="stroke4" d="M 503 532 Q 527 510 555 520 Q 795 608 782 549 Q 783 543 743 468 Q 736 458 741 453 Q 745 447 756 459 Q 852 532 894 549 Q 904 552 905 561 Q 906 574 876 592 Q 852 605 828 621 Q 800 637 783 630 Q 686 590 521 560 C 492 555 479 550 503 532 Z" fill="lightgray"></path>

      <path class="stroke5" d="M 568 72 Q 531 81 494 91 Q 482 94 483 86 Q 484 79 494 71 Q 569 7 596 -33 Q 611 -49 626 -36 Q 659 -3 661 82 Q 655 149 655 345 Q 656 382 667 407 Q 676 426 659 439 Q 634 461 604 470 Q 585 477 577 469 Q 571 462 582 447 Q 619 384 603 127 Q 597 82 589 74 Q 582 67 568 72 Z" fill="lightgray"></path>

      <path class="stroke6" d="M 444 320 Q 419 262 385 208 Q 364 180 381 144 Q 388 128 409 139 Q 460 181 468 264 Q 472 295 467 319 Q 463 328 456 328 Q 449 327 444 320 Z" fill="lightgray"></path>

      <path class="stroke7" d="M 738 307 Q 789 249 847 168 Q 860 146 876 139 Q 885 138 893 146 Q 908 159 900 204 Q 891 264 743 338 Q 734 345 731 332 Q 728 319 738 307 Z" fill="lightgray"></path>

      <text x="317" y="812">1</text>
      <text x="273" y="558">2</text>
      <text x="556" y="828">3</text>
      <text x="513" y="532">4</text>
      <text x="586" y="463">5</text>
      <text x="455" y="316">6</text>
      <text x="742" y="326">7</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I'm not the down-voter, but have you checked your result? The numbers are not in the right positions anymore.

Comment: yes, sorry for this quick answer, I've updated my post, thanks for the lights of @enxaneta

Answer (score 4):

```
    </path>
    </g>

  <g>
    <text x="317" y="812">1</text>
    <text x="273" y="500">2</text>
    <text x="556" y="828">3</text>
    <text x="513" y="532">4</text>
    <text x="586" y="463">5</text>
    <text x="455" y="316">6</text>
    <text x="742" y="326">7</text>
  </g>
</svg>
<script>
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('*[y]');
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
    elements[i].setAttribute('y', 958-(elements[i].getAttribute('y')));
</script>
```

958 comes from: 900(initial transform) + 58(character height).

Comment: I started to think that I actually dont have the "right" place (coordinates) for numbers, just positions of flipped ones. So perhaps negative y value is the correct one?