# How did you fix the upside text problem after transform - svg

Tags: javascript, svg, text, reverse, translate

I have one problem with svg.

How can I rotate all the points while preserving the Text.
Loads points from the file as circles with labels.
How do I use this transformation:
transform = "translate (0,400)
transform = "scale (1, -1).
It spins my points, but unfortunately the text turns around. Can someone help me?
How did you fix the upside text problem ?:)

Comment: transform the text back again.

Comment: I try but didnt work :/ i past example code http://jsfiddle.net/sk6vn7bf/

Comment: I see no [mcve] in the code. Feel free to edit it and add one.

Comment: Please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52062424/flip-most-of-an-svg-image-but-not-the-text-within-it/52063064#52063064

Comment: Maybe u see my code ? http://jsfiddle.net/1qonr82h/. If you delete line with transform in <text>, u see string

Comment: @enxaneta It works for one text , but if I get <text v-for > It doesnt work :/ Maybe u have some solution how I can get  text in loop ?